# Custom domain "403 Forbidden" using Github Pages

Tags: github, dns

I have created a webpage using Github Pages, from my understanding everything should be working fine, and the username.github.io link works perfectly fine. So, I added CNAME in the format of:

```
websitename.com
```

On the DNS settings on my domain's end, I've added the Github DNS IP's:

```
185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153
```

I've also added a CNAME record on my domain's end:

```
CNAME username.github.io
```

However, whenever I try accessing my website I receive a 403 Forbidden Error message.

> Forbidden:
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Some other information that may be necessary, the TTL is 1 hour, I do not have a .htaccess file, and I have done a very similar process on a different GitHub account for my personal portfolio which works perfectly fine. The only difference being where I purchased the domain from. If any other information is needed I will gladly add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove Github dns records on your domain's zone file. Just putting `CNAME` pointing to `username.github.io` is enough.